# Hibernate SQLQuery, addScalar() - Access the object inside a class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have an entity, Users.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class Users implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private UsersPK ids;

    private String password;
```

This entity has a UsersPK object. UsersPK is just a class that contains the primary keys of Users. For example, username. Also, the getters and setters for the primary keys.

Now, I want to access the database.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("//working sql statement here");
query.setParameter("username", username);
query.setParameter("password", password);

query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Users.class));
query.addScalar("username");
query.addScalar("password");

Users user1 = (Users) query.uniqueResult();

return user1;
```

I am having an error of -

- status 500 - Could not find setter for username.

I think it is because of the username is located on the UsersPK class and not in the Users class, but Users class has a UserPK object.

The problem is here how do I access that object so that I can use it in the `addScalar` function.

I have tried declaring `query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UsersPK.class));`
Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this

```
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Users.class));
query.addScalar("username");
query.addScalar("password");
```

for this

```
query.addScalar("username");
query.addScalar("password");
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Users.class));
```